# Accessing file in a different folder and absolute addressing within Netbeans without hardcoding

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans

So far, all my C++ development work was done in a Windows/Microsoft visual Studio IDE. The folder structure here was:

`C:\CppCode\Project\*.cpp` and `C:\CppCode\Project\*.h`

One of the lines within a `main.cpp` file in the `\Project\` folder above was

`FILE* fp = fopen("debug.txt","r");`

The effect of this was to create a `debug.txt` file in `C:\CppCode\Project\`

Now, I have a different Linux/Ubuntu machine with Netbeans IDE. The Windows `C:\CppCode\Project\` folder is available directly within the Ubuntu machine as `/home/Tryer/CppCode/Project/`. This is not a copy, but the original files. That is, any change I make in Ubuntu via NetBeans to `/home/Tryer/CppCode/Project/main.cpp` directly changes `C:\CppCode\Project\main.cpp` in the Windows machine.

I have created a project file within the Ubuntu machine in `/home/Tryer/Ubuntucode/`. The source and header files for this project are from `/home/Tryer/CppCode/Project/` folder.

When the code `FILE* fp = fopen("debug.txt","r");` is executed from within the Ubuntu machine, the `"debug.txt"` file is not created in the `C:\CppCode\Project\` folder of Windows (i.e., it is not created in the `/home/Tryer/CppCode/Project/` folder of Ubuntu). Yet, how can I achieve this though, with minimal hardcoding, possibly by using relative addressing?

Is there a way to obtain the absolute path of a source file in Ubuntu/Netbeans?

That way, suppose `$path$` was the absolute path, more specifically, the folder in which `main.cpp` resides, then something like:

`FILE* fp = fopen("$path$debug.txt","r");`

can work in Ubuntu/Netbeans?

Thanks.

Comment: Forget the project structure for a second.  Outside of the IDE, if you ran your executable file not from its directory but from another location and used a full path to it; where would you like your file to be created?

Comment: @RichardCritten I have multiple options/parameters that I have to specify within a .cpp file of the project and hence I NEVER run the executable by itself in Windows or from a different location. Every time, I open up the Visual Studio project, change the options in the .cpp file and rebuild and run the project from within Visual Studio.